# REP sent to old contract - can recover?

Tags: augur

This morning I sent REP from an Exodus wallet to Kraken, but it never arrived.

I checked the transaction and I saw :

TxHash:
0x1ca6810bd62642d748441cdc323dd6cbbdc19ff29f1f1d932decaa5bd5743a7e

TxReceipt Status:
Fail

Contract 0x48c80f1f4d53d5951e5d5438b54cba84f29f32a5 (REP-Augur-OLD)
 Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Bad jump destination]
  The ERC-20 Token Transfer might have Failed (ErrCode: unable to locate corresponding Transfer event log), check with sender.

There was no warning whatsoever when I sent my REP, and I hope they are not lost forever... I sent from a valid address to another valid address, that should not fail in anyway...

The question is : what should I do ?

Answer (score 2):

Ok I the updated Exodus to the latest version, scanned the blockchain again, and the original amount showed in my balance.

As the Exodus version was the latest, I tried to send again. The transcation went through this time !

Answer (score 0):

Your first step should be - contact support. All otc trading services like Kraken or [thejingstock](https://thejingstock.com/) have good support service and they should check all the info and tell you instructions step by step. And better to use updated Exodus.